Cannot find a solution for the CodeHS Phone Book Problem

Write a program that keeps a dictionary of names and their
corresponding phone numbers.
Repeatedly ask the user for a name. Then, do one of the following
three things, depending on what they enter:

If they enter nothing, exit the loop.
If they enter a name that exists as a key in your dictionary, simply print the corresponding phone number.
If they enter a name that is NOT in your dictionary as a key, ask the user for a phone number, and then put the name and phone number in
your dictionary.

Print out the final dictionary.

My solution works the intended way but for some reason it wont work for both sides of the CodeHS's check sheet to see if it is deemed correct in their algorithms eyes. I have tried pretty much everything I could think of as I am not the best coder but I can never get a solution that satisfies the interpreters needs. The boxes I'm trying to check off both have the same name; that being, "You should print the phone number for names who already exist in the dictionary". Please keep in mind I'm relatively new to Python. Any and all help is appreciated!
my_dict = {}

for i in range(3):
    name = input("Enter a name: ")
    phone_num = input("Enter a phone number: ")
    my_dict[name] = phone_num

print(my_dict)
name = input("Enter a name: ")
if name == "":
    exit()
if name in my_dict:
    print(my_dict[name])
if name not in my_dict:
    phone_num = input("Enter a phone number: ")
    my_dict[name] = phone_num
print(my_dict)

I have tried relentlessly to get this problem fixed and have had no avail.

Please post the problem description.

Are you really supposed to add a new number to the phone book when they try to look up a name and it doesn't exist?

Aside: Get in the habit of using elif and else for mutually exclusive conditions.

Problems:

You don't have a continuous loop. You start by asking for 3 names and numbers without checking whether the name is blank or already exists, then only do one lookup for an existing name.
When they enter an empty name when looking up, you exit the program without printing the dictionary.

The code to look up or add should all be inside a loop, and you can use break to end the loop.
while True: # continuous loop
    name = input("Enter a name: ")
    if name == "":
        break
    elif name in my_dict:
        print(my_dict[name])
    else:
        phone_num = input("Enter a phone number: ")
        my_dict[name] = phone_num
    
print(my_dict)


Thanks! I see what I did wrong now, and you help is greatly appreciated!
